# Can't get Bluetooth to work on Dell Latitude 6540

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, bluetooth, dell-latitude

I can't connect an Bluetooth devices to my Dell 6540 laptop. I tried two devices and neither works.

I have Bluetooth headphones SHB7000 that I can connect to from my cell phone. I also have a Samsung Galaxy s6 that I can pair to a different laptop.

I went to the Dell website and installed the latest Bluetooth driver. No luck.

I made sure that the Bluetooth button is turned on.

I can pair the phone with the laptop, but it seems like the connection is then dropped. I can't send any files or see the device in the device manager.

I can pair the headphones, but then it seems like the connection is dropped. When I click on the volume mixer, I do not see the headphones listed.

There are no driver issues as per the device manager.

I also ran the Dell automatic driver detection and installed any updates.

Has anyone been able to get Bluetooth to work on this?

Comment: Could be a hardware fault, such as the Bluetooth aerial that is connected to the mini PCI card has been unplugged or broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a GPO at work blocking it from functioning. It works when I disconnect from the network. Otherwise, I click on Bluetooth in the task bar, and click show devices. I double click on the headphones, and it says "No available services or remote devices connection failure". Go figure!